# Liferay 6.2 Portal Instances Portal Admin

Tags: liferay, instance, liferay-6, administration

I am using Liferay 6.2 and I am creating one Portal Instance say abc.com, I have done necessary config to access the second URL abc.com and I login with test@abc.com which logs in to the abc instance where I can add the portets to page & create page. 
But I do not see or have access to control panel, Site settings in abc.com Portal Instance.

- Please let me know how this user test@abc.com can have access to admin options ? Control Panel for managing sites and content in abc portal instance ?
- How users, groups, role can be controlled for this portal instance ? as the users of abc.com does not display in default liferay.com instance control panel ?
- I need to configure LDAP for abc.com instance I need access to control panel how this can be done ?

Can anyone please share the experience of using Portal Instance and how the administration can be done for managing above scenarios in new Instances ?

Appreciate your inputs on above.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It's just like in the default instance that you always have when running Liferay: The user you login with must have the proper permissions, e.g. you need to assign the "Administrator" role, then the rest of your questions will automatically be solved.

The only section you won't see in secondary portal instances is the "Server" section in Control Panel - all the other sections are there.

Comment: Thanks Olaf for the reply, Server section is fine if not visible but I am unable to see / have access to control panel in Second Instance. What liferay say is you directly use test@abc.com / test for the instance it should automatically have the administrator role. But I think its not getting the Admin role. To assign user to Administrator role it will have to be done through backend ? as there is no option to assign user as Control Panel is not visible. I hope you got the problem.

Comment: I am noticing strange problem in local machine liferay instance this works fine test@abc.com gets the admin access to control panel. But doing the same on Amazon Instance is not getting the admin access. Not sure what is causing that behavior.

Comment: I've not tried this feature in a long time - it always worked for me as described. Not sure how to reproduce different behaviour. Which version are you running?

Comment: Olaf I figured out the issue it was due to Amazon Route 53 mapping for my URL, I was giving the CNAME earlier when I use the Public IP for Rouse 53 and accessed it.. It made the user in Second Portal Instance as Admin.. Strange Behavior but got it working :) Thanks !